# update-database to dll in EntityFramework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Update-Database executed on class library in a solution.
I have `Configuration:DbMigrationsConfiguration<TestContext>` class in my `Data.dll` , I add reference `Data.dll` on other project for example console app and now I want to set `Update-Database` in Package Manager Console.How I can do that?

Comment: Do you have access to `Data` project sources, too?

Comment: If you mean access source code from console app ,I have not any access to Data.dll sources from console app.

Comment: Could you find a solution?